# In winston for Node.js is there a way to suppress log level from message?

Tags: express, winston

I'm using winston to stream log messages from Express based on various comments elsewhere, my setup is essentially:

```
var express = require("express"),
    winston = require("winston");

// enable web server logging; pipe those log messages through winston
var requestLogger = new (winston.Logger)(
        {
            transports: [
                new (winston.transports.File)(
                    {
                        filename: "logs/request.log",
                        json: false,
                        timestamp: false
                    }
                )
            ]
        }
    ),
    winstonStream = {
        write: function(message, encoding) {
            requestLogger.info(message.replace(/(\r?\n)$/, ''));
        }
    };

this.use(express.logger({stream: winstonStream}));
```

But I'd like a way to suppress the output of the log level because I know for this particular logger it will always be "info". So rather than:

```
info: 127.0.0.1 - - [Fri, 20 Sep 2013 13:48:02 GMT] "POST /v1/submission HTTP/1.1" 200 261 "http://localhost:8887/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36"
```

I would get:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [Fri, 20 Sep 2013 13:48:02 GMT] "POST /v1/submission HTTP/1.1" 200 261 "http://localhost:8887/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.65 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Did you ever figure something out? I'm logging info from a load test, and I want to capture info for stats. As it is, I have to remove this post run.